# Killing a process in linux

Tags: linux, kill, pkill

I am trying to kill a process in linux

```
ps -aux
root     14074  0.0  0.4 6586120 67452 pts/0   Sl   22:45   0:01 java -cp target/cronscheduler-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.cronscheduler.QuartzMain
```

Kill the process in the stop script using the below command

```
ps aux | grep "java -cp target/cronscheduler-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.cronscheduler.QuartzMain" | \
grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}' | xargs kill -9
```

Issue is this command works fine when **cronscheduler.QuartzMain** is running. But when this process is already killed then the above command throws error

```
Usage:
 kill [options] <pid|name> [...]
```

Your inputs on removing the errors are appreciated

Comment: Do you want to remove the error message, or simply ignore it?

Comment: As there will be no process running you will not get any process id so final command will don't have process id

Comment: @ Evert I want to remove the error message

Answer (score 1):

`pkill` can search through the complete command line. Try

```
pkill -9 -f 'java -cp target/cronscheduler-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.cronscheduler.QuartzMain'
```

Your command may create errors, because it sends more than the pid (the complete line from `ps`) to kill.

Comment: Looks like you just took it from the question but normally `-9` should be avoided.

Comment: Yes, you should use `-9` only if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

One of the solution I found was to redirect the error message :
cat /etc/*.conf 2> /dev/null

Answer (score 0):

```
ps aux | grep httpd

httpd  3486  0.0  0.1   4248  1432 ?        S    Jul31   0:00 /usr/sbin/httpd -f /etc/httpd/httpd.conf

# kill 3486
```

OR

```
$ sudo kill 3486
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try below this will help in clearing the child process id's as well.

```
for i in `ps -ef| grep "java -cp target/cronscheduler-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar com.cronscheduler.QuartzMain" | grep -v grep | awk '{print $2}'`        
do
     ptree $i|awk '{print $1}' >>pids.txt
done
for i in $(cat pids.txt)
do
     kill -9 $i
done
```